# Application broken after changing ToPromise() to Last/FirstvalueFrom()

Tags: promise, pagination, nestjs

I have this Interceptor which is responsible for the pagination of my application, it has the first part which used to check if the response of http was ok.

```
try {
  //next.handle().pipe(map((data) => ({ data })));
  const data = await next.handle().toPromise();
  return data.status < 300
    ? this.mountPagination(data)
    : this.getResponseStatus(data, context);
} catch (error) {
  return throwError(this.createHttpException(error));
}
```

}

If it was ok, then it move on and build the pagination.

After the toPromise was deprecated, I wasn't able to change it by the lastvaluefrom

**UPDATE**

```
try {
  const data = next.handle().pipe(map((data) => ({ data })));
  return this.mountPagination(data);
} catch (error) {
  return throwError(this.createHttpException(error));
}
```

}

This is what i'm trying to correct
But the variable data is an observable after that, which I can't get the status from it

Comment: share the broken code with us

Comment: try {
      const data = next.handle().pipe(map((data) => ({ data })));
      return this.mountPagination(data);

      //const data = await next.handle().toPromise();
      //return data.status < 300
      //  ? this.mountPagination(data)
      //: this.getResponseStatus(data, context);
    } catch (error) {
      return throwError(this.createHttpException(error));
    }
  }

It is one of the different ways that i tried but it returns an observable, which i'm not able to get the status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to convert from ToPromise() to First/LastValueFrom:

```
const data = await next.handle().toPromise();
```

to

```
const data = await lastValueFrom(next.handle());
```

Hope this helps